# Prob. 8(c), Sec. 17, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: What is the relation between $\overline{A-B}$ and $\overline{A}-\overline{B}$?

Tags: general-topology

Here is Prob. 8 (c), Sec. 17, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $A$, $B$ denote subsets of a (topological) space $X$. Determine whether the following equation holds; if an equality fails, determine whether one of the inclusions $\subset$ or $\supset$ holds. 
>   $$ \overline{A-B} = \overline{A} - \overline{B}. $$

My Attempt:

> In the space  $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, let $A$ denote the set of all rational numbers, and let $B$ denote the set of all irrational numbers. Then we note that $$\overline{A} = \mathbb{R} = \overline{B},$$ and also 
>   $$ \overline{A - B} = \overline{A} = \mathbb{R}.  $$
>   So
>   $$ \overline{ A-B } \not\subset \overline{A} - \overline{B}. $$
>   Thus the equation does not hold in general.

Is this example correct? If so, then what next? Can we show that 
$$\overline{A} - \overline{B} \subset \overline{A-B}?$$

Comment: Good example you have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\overline A\setminus\overline B\subseteq\overline{A\setminus B}.$ To see this, consider any point $p\in\overline A\setminus\overline B;$ we want to show that $p\in\overline{A\setminus B}.$ Consider any neighborhood $U$ of $p;$ we want to show that $U$ meets $A\setminus B.$ Since $p\notin\overline B,$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ which is disjoint from $B.$ Then $W=U\cap V$ is a neighborhood of $p$ which is disjoint from $B,$ but $W$ meets $A,$ so $W$ meets $A\setminus B,$ and $W\subseteq U,$ so $U$ meets $A\setminus B.$

Answer (score 6):

We can! I used the facts that $D \subset \overline{D}$, then that if $A$ is contained in a closed set, $\bar{A}$ is also, and that the union of two closed sets is closed.
$$\begin{align} 
A &= (A-B) \cup B \\
A &\subset \overline{A-B} \cup \overline{B} \\
\overline{A} &\subset \overline{A-B} \cup \overline{B} \\
\overline{A} - \overline{B} &\subset \overline{A-B}
\end{align}$$